# multilingual HTML w/JQuery and nested JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json, multilingual

I prepared a simple multilingual website with the following JQuery code:

```
(function() {
  var language, translate;

  translate = function(jsdata) {
    $('[tkey]').each(function(index) {
      var strTr;
      strTr = jsdata[$(this).attr('tkey')];
      $(this).html(strTr);
    });
  };

  language = $.cookie('language');

  if (language === 'en') {
    $.getJSON('en.json', translate);
  } else {
    $.getJSON('hu.json', translate);
    $('#eng').show(0);
    $('#hun').hide(0);
  }

}).call(this);
```

If store the data in two simple JSON files such as

en.json

```
{
  "title" : "test1",
  "body" : "Hello Word!"
}
```

hu.json

```
{
  "title" : "teszt1",
  "body" : "Szia Világ!"
}
```

I can call the content in HTML in the following way

```
<p tkey='title'></p>
<p tkey='body'></p>
```

Actually, I would like to use nested JSON files generated from some md files like these

en.json

```
{
  "1.md": {
    "title": "test 1", "body": "Hello Word!"
  },
  "2.md": {
    "title": "test 2", "body": "Hello Word again!"
  }
}
```

hu.json

```
{
  "1.md": {
    "title": "teszt 1", "body": "Szia Világ!"
  },
  "2.md": {
    "title": "teszt 2", "body": "Szia Világ megint!"
  }
}
```

Could you help me, how can I call them in HTML?

```
<p tkey='1.md.title'></p>
<p tkey='1.md.body'></p>
```

does not work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like you're on the right path. You seeing errors?

Comment: No errors but the content do not appear.

Comment: At the bottom of your each loop, add: console.log("TX", $(this).attr('tkey')); and see what it gets.

Comment: `strTr = jsdata[$(this).attr('tkey')];` for your second json is not ok because mean `jsdata['1.md.title']` and not exists in your jsdata. Your jsdata must be like `jsdata['1.md']['title']` so `$(this).attr('tkey')` cannot working (for your second json) but work in your first json
You need to save your path in `tkey` attribute in other way to manage multiple obiect paths

Answer (score 1):

If your first example work, then a fastest way to working the second must be like this:

```
<p tkey1="1.md" tkey2="title"></p>
<p tkey1="1.md" tkey2="body"></p>
```

and your `translate` function

```
  translate = function(jsdata) {
    $('[tkey1]').each(function(index) {
      var strTr;
      strTr = jsdata[$(this).attr('tkey1')][$(this).attr('tkey2')];
      $(this).html(strTr);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Be welcome. If it work, you can select my answer as accepted answer (under the voting arrows)